# Will Windows dcdiag.exe interrupt any services on a production system?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, active-directory, interrupt

Will the running the Windows [dcdiag.exe command-line tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731968(WS.10).aspx) on a Server 2008 R2 system interfere with **any** services on that machine?

A small amount of CPU and network traffic usage is acceptable, but the system is live and applications on the machine must remain up and running without interruption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`didiag.exe` is safe to run on a production machine. It's a reporting tool only and doesn't attempt to take corrective actions (stopping / starting services, making configuration changes, etc).

Comment: It can make some changes depending on the switches used. E.g. if the /fix switch is used. Regardless it is safe to use.

Answer (score 3):

No, dcdiag.exe will not interfere with any services.